# Sharepoint 2013 Search anonymous REST API query always returns zero results

Tags: 2013, search, rest, search-api

**TLDR version**: Is there some trick to using `refinementFilters` or a result set in an anonymous query to the Sharepoint Search REST API?  Whenever I try, I get zero results, even though it returns all results if `refinementFilters` / result set is removed.

**Long version**:

Background: We need to modify a bunch of websites to use a new system for search functionality as the old system was decommissioned.

So, I've set up a Search Service application within our self-hosted Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise server which is indexing the required data (crawling a couple of websites and a couple of file shares in the company intranet), which works as expected.

I can use the search app's REST API from a browser and filter the search results based on content source with `refinementFilters='ContentSource:equals("whatever")'`, so results from one website only show up where intended.

However, the browser negotiates an auth token along with the request, and I need to call that API server-side from the webserver that's building the search pages. I really don't want to have to deal with authentication from the webserver at all since all this is only happening inside our intranet anyway.

Of course, as soon as I make the request from a proper REST client (e.g. Postman) or more importantly via cURL (PHP), obviously it's not going to work due to permissions.  So I've enabled anonymous access and set up the `QueryPropertiesTemplate` according to these two guides:

https://support.cloudshare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200701115-How-to-Enable-Anonymous-Access-to-a-SharePoint-2013-site

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/configuring-sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api-anonymous-users/

Which works fine, except that it returns every result from every content source.  As soon as I add the `refinementFilters` from earlier, I get zero results.

No error messages, just...nothing.

My gut feeling is that this is a permissions problem but I can't figure out what else to change?

I'm fairly new to Sharepoint so I've probably just missed a checkbox somewhere.  I've also tried using a result source that does the filtering and setting its ID in the query, but get the exact same result.

I've checked out all the similar questions I could find here, but none of them addressed this issue.

Comment: Are your refinable properties marked "Safe". This is required to return results to an anonymous user.